# Pass an array of math.functions as parameters with multiple variables

Tags: python

Basically what I want is a method that takes two arrays

```
array1=[1, 2, 3]
array2=[math.pow(x, 3), math.pow(x, 2)+x, 3*x]
```

And inside the method uses the first element of array1 as x in the first function of array1, the second element of array2 as the x in the second function of array2 and so on.

```
def cal(array1, array2):
```

I have looking through stackoverflow and the closes I got was using `lambda` or using a function to call the method, but none of them solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does literally what you say you want:

```
import math

array1 = [1, 2, 3]
array2 = ['math.pow(x, 3)', 'math.pow(x, 2)+x', '3*x']

def cal(values, expressions):
    return [eval(expression, {'math': math, '__builtins__': None}, {'x': value})
                for value, expression in zip(values, expressions)]

print(cal(array1, array2))
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 6.0, 9]
```

Comment: @martineau I'm very curious, how did you come to understand that the functions are being saved as strings, and therefore an eval is needed?

Comment: @mu無: The title of the question mentions passing an array of functions, although the sample code shows an array of expressions, so I chose the simplest way to represent the latter and execute them in varying contexts — which I assumed is what they really meant — plus anything else would have required more scaffolding to work (such as using `lamda`s or class methods).

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [python lambda functions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
>>> import math
>>> array1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> array2 = [lambda x: math.pow(x, 3), lambda x: math.pow(x, 2)+x, lambda x: 3*x]
>>> for function in array2:
...     print map(function, array1)
... 
[1.0, 8.0, 27.0]
[2.0, 6.0, 12.0]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Basically, the functions are each stored as a callable lambda within an array, and then, each of the functions is called for all values of array1 using the builtin `map`.

As a list comprehension, which returns list of list:

```
>>> [map(function, array1) for function in array2]
[[1.0, 8.0, 27.0], [2.0, 6.0, 12.0], [3, 6, 9]]
```

If you want to apply the functions to each item based on the same index, you can use:

```
>>> [y(x) for (x, y) in zip(array1, array2)]
[1.0, 6.0, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks @mu 無 , the part I was missing was the builtin `map`.
Do you know any built in function that does the same but using a non-iterable parameter instead of going through the whole list?
I can obtain the desired output with   
    `
    n = 0
    array = []
    for function in array2:
        new_array= map(function, array1)
        array.append(new_array[n])
        n=n+1
    `
    However, is a waste of resources.

Comment: @cadv I'm not sure if I understood you completely. As far as I know, the map function is the usual way to do this; you could use a list comprehension to get the cumulative result, as in the updated answer. If you are looking for applying functions based on same index, have a look at zip.